# os.chmod not setting GID bit

Tags: python, chmod

I am trying to use os.chmod to set directory permissions to ensure the webserver has write permissions to folders created by the server. Normally I would set the root folder GID bit in the shell and all subfolders would keep the GID. Creation of the root folders is dynamic so I need to do this in python.

I am using this

```
os.chmod(user_dir, 2775)
```

But the results are this

```
d-ws-w-rwt
```

And I want this

```
drwxrwsr-x
```

What numbers do I need in the mode?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number should be in octal, not decimal. Use:

```
os.chmod(user_dir, 02775)
```